# How can I use batch commands to set the permissions of a directory to allow domain users full access

Tags: windows, command-line

Basically, I have a directory that domain users need to have full access to. They use a batch file to open the piece of software that they use for their work, and this piece of software needs full access to this directory on their C Drive.

I want to add commands to the batch file to make sure this is always the case.

Thanks

Comment: First, the domain users will need "write permissions" to this directory. But since you did not specify an OS, well, we'll just have to use our psychic powers. . .

Comment: Yes, obviously I'm asking about the C drive on my Linux box, hooked up to my Mac OS domain...